Is $\Gamma \vDash B$ in propositional logic a r.e. problem?
One version of the compactness theorem in propositional logic is as follows: if $\Gamma \vDash B$, then there is a finite $\Delta \subseteq \Gamma$ s.t. $\Delta \vDash B$.
However, this by itself does not make the reverse true. Yet, it seems to me that the reverse is true, which would then result in the equivalence: $\Gamma \vDash B$ $\Leftrightarrow ~\text{there is a finite} ~\Delta \subseteq \Gamma$ s.t. $\Delta \vDash B$.
My proof for the reverse
Suppose not, $\Gamma \not \vDash B$, then there is $\phi$ s.t. $\phi(S)=T$ for every $S \in \Gamma$ but $\phi(B)=F$. $\phi$ satisfies $\Delta$. By our hypothesis $\phi(B)=T$. This is a contradiction.
Does it mean that $\Gamma \vDash B$ in propositional logic is an r.e. problem: loop over all the subsets of $\Gamma$, if one of them tautologically implies $B$, return Yes?

Yes, correct. If $\Gamma \vDash B$, then by Completeness $\Gamma \vdash B$. But a derivation is a finite sequence of formula: thus, it can use only a finite number of members of $\Gamma$.

See also here for more insights. Note that deciding if $\Gamma \models B$ or not amounts to decide if $\Gamma \cup {\lnot B}$ is satisfiable or not.

This question seems quite muddled. I suggest you to begin with a standard statement of the compactness theorem (heeding the biconditionals) and carry on from there.
